# Alphabetical sorting in treeset not working

Tags: java, sorting, collections, treeset

Hi, my code is like this:

```
TreeSet<String> ts=new TreeSet<String>();

ts.add("Testtxt");
ts.add("Testxml");
ts.add("docdoc");
ts.add("ePeoplexml");
ts.add("fantasyxlsx");
ts.add("idaddedgif");
ts.add("idaddedrtf");

System.out.println("Tree set :: "+ts);
```

Output:

```
Tree set :: [Testtxt, Testxml, docdoc, ePeoplexml, fantasyxlsx, idaddedgif, idaddedrtf]
```

It's not sorting all strings in alphabetical order.Can any one help how to achieve an ascending order of the strings in `treeset`.

Thanks
Madhu.

Answer (score 25):

The sorting is fine. It is done in case-sensitive manner. Since unicode code point of `T` comes before `d`, so, `Testtxt` comes before `docdoc` in sorted set.

Since you want to do *case insensitive* sorting, you can use a pre-defined static [CASE_INSENSITIVE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER) comparator defined in `String` class. Instantiate your `TreeSet` like this:

```
TreeSet<String> ts=new TreeSet<String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```