# Treeset Ordering on string Not performed

Tags: collections, treeset

This might look dulicate question and is a bit relevant to

[Alphabetical sorting in treeset not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18333154/alphabetical-sorting-in-treeset-not-working)

I have a Treeset containing

```
TreeSet<String> ts=new TreeSet<String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);

        ts.add("D1");
        ts.add("D9");
        ts.add("D5");
        ts.add("D3");
        ts.add("D8");
```

which gives me,

```
Tree set :: [D1, D3, D5, D8, D9]
```

but if i add double digits to my "D"

```
    ts.add("D1");
    ts.add("D9");
    ts.add("D5");
    ts.add("D3");
    ts.add("D8");
    ts.add("D11");
    ts.add("D18");
    ts.add("D17");
    ts.add("D13");
```

i get,

```
Tree set :: [D1, D11, D13, D17, D18, D3, D5, D8, D9]
```

which aint correct....Please help!

Comment: It seems correct to me. First the first character is taken into account for ordering, then the second, ...

Answer (score 0):

Sorting is performed alphabetically - all 1 (ones) are coming before 3, then comes 5, 8, 9.

If you want to have numeric sorting you need to implement your own comparator.